# Wrong Json Parsing

Tags: javascript, json

I am sending a JSON string having a long type property from the server and when I am getting the response in the client the long value is converted to a different value.I am not able to find out the problem.Here is the sample JSON string.uuid property giving right value but tweetId does not.

**{"uuid":"6160432f-1f68-4a76-afba-664d680bd23e","tweetId":906458203956927529}**

Comment: are you de/serializing `tweetId` to/from an int by any chance?

Comment: We need to see how the client handles it.  Sounds like it's just deserializing to the wrong type.

Comment: try sending the tweetId converting to **String** as Js has highest possible value 9007199254740991.

Comment: What do you mean by "long type property"?

Comment: How can I mention tweetId as a String type.